# Generate random intervals with given density and overlapping

Tags: algorithm, random, statistics

I am in search of algorithm (possibly, approximate) that will generate test data.

We have large integer interval `[0, n)`, `n` may be up to 10^9. We want to generate a number of smaller intervals (possibly, overlapping) of length `k` each, all of which fit inside this large interval and also satisfy following properties:

1. Number of "cells" covered by these intervals divided by `n` must be equal to `density` (<=1.0)
2. Every cell covered by at least one interval is actually covered by `overlapping` (>=1.0) intervals on average. E.g. degenerate case of overlap_factor=1.0 means that no two intervals intersect.
3. Interval positions should be distributed uniformly randomly in all other respects

Achieving both (1) and (2) is what makes this problem difficult. The algorithm should produce an array of interval positions.

Image below demonstrates one of the solutions for n=20, k=4, density=0.5, overlapping=1.6:

```
    ◼◼◼◼
     ◼◼◼◼
   ◼◼◼◼     ◼◼◼◼
       ↓↓↓
◻◻◻◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻
0                  19

density = 10/20 = 0.5
overlapping = 4*4/10 = 1.6
```

Real-world applications will opearte with larger values: n ≤ 10^9, k ∈ [1 .. 10^6], density ∈ [0.01 .. 1.0], overlapping ∈ [1.0..5.0].

Because this algorithm is intended to generate test data, approximate solution would be fine.

Comment: Can you give definition of density and overlapping?

Comment: I think there is a pretty straightforward solution to this If I'm understanding it correctly from this example.

Comment: @vish4071, density is the number of filled (black) cells divided by `n`. In the image above, there are 10 black cells, which gives density of 0.5. Density=1.0 means that every point is covered by at least one interval (everything is "black"), density 0.0 means that there are no intervals present. Overlapping is computed as `number_of_intervals * k / number_of_black_cells`.

Comment: We can immediately derive number of intervals we need to generate: `number_of_intervals = n*density*overlapping/k`. But I do not see any trivial way how to find positions for these intervals to satisfy the above conditions.